# animate function done than do other

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

i want to animate 4 sections step by step and i am using this code..

```
$(".bar_1").animate(
height: "100px",
500,
function(){
   $(".bar_2").animate(
   height: "100px",
   500,
   function(){
      $(".bar_3").animate(
      height: "100px",
      500,
      function(){
         $(".bar_4").animate(
         height: "100px",
         500,
         function(){
             ///Similarity Next Bars
         });
      });

   });
});
```

I there any possibility that i can create a function that will run for some specific given times automatically. mean if i use above method to animate .bar_1 to .bar_7 my coding became very complex

Comment: Event proxy can be a nice way to strip your nested callbacks. See the document. https://github.com/JacksonTian/eventproxy/blob/master/README_en.md

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each element you want to animate the class "bar". Then you can do this:

```
var $bars = $('.bar');
(function animateBar(i) {
    $bars.eq(i).animate({ height: "100px" }, 500, function() {
        animateBar(i + 1);
    });
})(0);
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KKD5w/)

Comment: What is triggering the animation to start?

Comment: @VIDesignz - The `animateBar` function is called immediately because of the `(0)` right after it. That gets it going with `i` as `0`. Eventually `i` will get passed the end, so `$bars.eq(i)` will be an empty jQuery object. When `.animate()` is called on that empty object, the looping stops.

Comment: @VIDesignz - This is often referred to as an "immediately invoked function expression" (IIFE). The parentheses around the function are not necessary, but are a convention to signal that the function is going to be immediately invoked.

Comment: That's pretty awesome, I understood the rest of the script but had never seen the (0).  I would always write a function and then call the function.

Comment: @VIDesignz - Yes. As you pointed out, in this case you could just declare the function, and then call it. Immediately invoking it in this case just saves a line of code. This technique is often used though with anonymous functions.

Comment: This is just sick! Anonymous? Like one-off functions?

Comment: @VIDesignz - I'm not sure I would say "one-off" functions. Anonymous functions can serve certain purposes, like creating a scope or setting up a closure. For an example, look inside the jQuery library. The first line of code you see is an anonymous function that is immediately invoked. Of course, you have to look at the last line to see where it is invoked. (Notice they use the convention of surrounding the function with parentheses.)

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly do it by recursively poping and shifting jQuery elements collection:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/dJ79q/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar_1">Number 1</div>
<div class="bar_2">Number 2</div>
<div class="bar_3">Number 3</div>
<div class="bar_4">Number 4</div>
```

**JS**

Starting off by caching a collection of dom elements to work on, and another variable `$elementsArray` which initialy hold elements off of `$elements` to work on

```
var $elementsArray = -1;
var $elements = $("div");
```

A handy function called `animate( element )` which will animate the element passed and do a simple callback to function outlined further down:

```
function animate( element ) {
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.animate({height:"100px"}, 500, sequentialyAnimate );
}
```

Main function called `sequentialyAnimate( $elements )` which will initialy recieve an `$elements` collection to start off the process

```
function sequentialyAnimate( $elements ) {
    if ( $elements != undefined ) {
        $elementsArray = $elements; // adding $elements to $elementsArray
    }
    animationElement = $elementsArray.get(0); // get the first element - this will be a DOM element
    $elementsArray = $elementsArray.slice(1); // remove it from the array
    animate( animationElement ); // animate the current DOM element
}
```

Finaly, just call the above function with necessary jQuery elements collection to kick things off:

```
sequentialyAnimate( $elements );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution with a mini code

**Using Delay**

```
Set a timer to delay execution of subsequent items in the queue.
```

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $delay = [];
    for($i=1;$i<8;$i++){
    $delay[$i] = 3000 * ($i-1)
        $(".bar_"+$i).delay($delay[$i]).animate({height: 100},3000);

    }
    })
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/wmgZ3/

More about [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Hope it helps you :)